# Android Studio Error:Failed to resolve: com.facebook.react:react-native:+?

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I am trying to use Android Studio to help develop a react native Android bridge module.

How do I resolve this error?

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.facebook.react:react-native:+

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/
         file:/Users/edward3/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/Users/edward3/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/
         file:/Users/edward3/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/Users/edward3/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
```

I opened the /MyBridgeModule/android/ folder using Android Studio.

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
       warning 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

This can be possible when using `+` in reference of Version. Try to use specific version when going offline `+` may not work with Offine gradle build in android studio or may this refer to this issue [GitHub Issue referene to same](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/359)